# How to snap two meshes across similar geometry

Tags: scripting, transforms, snapping

I have a model of a scene that is split into two sections like so:

O____/\__

_/\_____-*-*-__

Imagine that the first line is one mesh and the second line is the other half of the mesh of the whole scene. Also the /\ shape is the SAME object in both halves and I want to align these two meshes using the /\ as a reference point. So the combined scene mesh would look like this:

O____/\_____-*-*-__

Vertex snap would work **BUT** the two halves are rotated in a way that they dont line up exactly. So it needs to be a match on at least 3 vertices to match up perfectly. In my head the solution is to pick a triangle on the /\ shape in both halves and somehow have the software automatically move and rotate one of the meshes so that the triangles overlap perfectly.

Can I achieve this with Blender?

Comment: You could perhaps get some help from this python script... http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Precise_Align

Comment: @m.ardito This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!